# Copying a Boolean array on Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy, boolean

I'm trying to copy a Boolean array into another boolean array. This is that I'm trying:

```
public class Nucleo {
private boolean[] nivel;

public Nucleo(boolean[] carga, double x, int i){ //Copy the array
    for(int j=0; j<carga.length; j++){ 
        nivel[j]=carga[j];
    }

    x=potencia;
    i=porcentaje;

}
```

I send the array `boolean[] carga` from the `main`. Like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean[] niveles = new boolean[8];
    rellniveles(niveles);
    Nucleo nivel1= new Nucleo(niveles, 5, 4);
    nivel1.getPotencia();
}

public static void rellniveles(boolean[] niv){ //Fill the array
    niv[0]=true;
    niv[1]=true;
    niv[2]=true;
    niv[3]=true;
    niv[4]=true;
    niv[5]=true;
    niv[6]=false;
    niv[7]=false;

}
```

If I try to copy with `"System.arraycopy( carga, 0, nivel, 0, carga.length );"`

I get the error: `"Source not found".`

I'm using Eclipse. I get this error with System.arraycopy() i.imgur.com/pbGrKz6.png

Comment: Please show the code that gives you the error, not the one that supposedly works.

Comment: And by the way, where are you allocating memory to `boolean[] nivel`?

Comment: Ok, sorry a lot. How said João Fernandes, I didn't reserved memory to the array. I can't believe that. 

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrays.copyOf(boolean[] original, int newLength)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int%29) should help you.

E.g.:

```
public Nucleo(boolean[] carga, double x, int i) {
    this.nivel = (carga == null) ? null : Arrays.copyOf(carga, carga.length);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That message is thrown by Eclipse, when you try to access the source code of a method, that you do not have access to. It does not mean there is any error in your code.

The method you are looking for, System.arrayCopy() is part of Java's core library, so can be found in src.zip that should be included with your JDK.

The following link explains how to link it to your Eclipse environment - http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/08/attaching-java-source-with-eclipse-ide/

In this case, however, System.arrayCopy() is not implemented in Java, but natively, so you will not be able to look into the source code, at least not Java source code.

If you are having an actual problem copying an array (it is not clear from your question) - then following timonik's example above may help.